# my integer gets printed out wrong in mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I have an assignment to implement herons formula in mips which is as follows

```
A^2=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)
```

where `s` is `(a+b+c)/2` and `a`, `b` and `c` are the sides of a triangle.

The assignment is to print out `A^2` but whenever I try to do this I always get `0.0x` instead of `x`. For example, if I input `a,b,c=2` I should get `3` but I get `0.03`.

```
main:
li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s1, $v0

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s2, $v0

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s3, $v0

syscall

add $s0,$s1,$s2
add $s0,$s0,$s3
div $s0,$s0,2 
sub $s1,$s0,$s1
sub $s2,$s0,$s2
sub $s3,$s0,$s3
mul $s0,$s0,$s1
mul $s0,$s0,$s2
mul $s0,$s0,$s3

li $v0,1
add $a0,$s0,$zero
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: Why is there a stray `syscall` before the first `add`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you input 2 for all three values, you'll have `$v0 = 2` after the final `read_int` system call.

Right after that you have an extra `syscall` instruction that shouldn't be there. So you're executing system call 2, [which is `print_float`](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html). And apparently `$f12` happened to contain the value 0 at that point, so that system call prints `0.0`.

And then you print your result (e.g. 3) at the end, so you get `0.03`.